# Recursive variadic template instation fails

Tags: c++, templates, variadic

What is the reason, that in the following example the instantiaton with three int is working with the second function template but not with the first one. 
Additional: with the types State1 / State1 it isn't working either.

```
struct State1{};
struct State2{};

#if 0
template<typename none = void>
constexpr void f()
{
}
template<typename First, typename... Rest>
constexpr void f()
{
    f<Rest...>();
}
#else
template<typename none = void>
constexpr void f()
{
}
template<int First, int... Rest>
constexpr void f()
{
    f<Rest...>();
}
#endif
void test()
{
   f<1, 2, 3>();
//    f<State1, State2>();
}
```

Thank you any hints!

Comment: "It isn't working" is not a problem description.

Comment: `1` is not a type, and vice-versa.

Comment: One template expects a type, you feed it an integer literal. The other template expects an integer, you feed it a type. How are you surprised this doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

The problem in the first case is that both template specializations match when you pass a single template parameter (a parameter pack can be empty), so the overload set contains more than one candidate. You can use SFINAE to make the second one fail to instantiate:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct State1{};
struct State2{};

template<typename none = void>
constexpr auto f() -> void
{
}

template<typename First, typename... Rest>
constexpr auto f() -> std::enable_if<sizeof...(Rest), void>::type
    // This will not instantiate when the parameter pack is empty
    // And the overload set will contain only the candidate above
{
    f<Rest...>();
}

int main()
{
  f<State1, State2>();

  return 0;
}
```